# instead of image showing html code

Tags: kendo-ui

I am running one project where i used jquery kendo row template. Here i have to show an url image which is inside div, this complete html code i put in the model
and that model property i am calling in kendo grid row template.
Below is the code of html kendo grid:

```html
 <table id="grid" style="width:100%">
               <colgroup>
                   <col class="photo" />
                   <col class="details" />
                   <col />
               </colgroup>
               <thead style="display:none">
                   <tr>

                       <th>
                           Details
                       </th>

                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                       <td colspan="3"></td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>
           <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
               <tr>
                   <td style="width:30%">
                       <a href="#: Link #" class="name" style="color:blue">#: GetName #</a>
                      
                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-sm-4">
                              #: imagelink #
                           </div>
                          
                       </div>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </script>
```

and this imagelink property contains this html code:

```html
<div class="th" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 116px; height: 65px"><a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXR8nnu_fZw23'><div style='margin-top:-11px'><img src='https://img.youtube.com/vi/XXR8nnu_fZw/default.jpg?h=90' width='116' alt='Video for marathon m5 youtube' align='middle'></div><div style='position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;font-size:11px;color:#fff;background-color:#222;padding:1px 3px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;text-align:right'>&#9658; 4:14</div></a></div>
```

This complete tag if i used outside of this grid then it's working fine showing the image but the same is using inside grid showing the same html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `#: imagelink #` with `#= imagelink #`

`#= #` - value is rendered as HTML

`#: #` - HTML encoding is used to display value

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

Comment: Hey thanks Gene it's working as i expected thanks a lot. I am marking it as  answer.